# Magento 1.9 - Creating a new page not working

Tags: magento, module

I'm trying to create a new page to my module without success. I have created a module with the contents:

> app\code\local\CompanyName\Insignias\etc\config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <CompanyName_Insignias>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </CompanyName_Insignias>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <insignias>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>CompanyName_Insignias</module>
                    <frontName>insignias</frontName>
                </args>
            </insignias>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <insignias>
                    <file>insignias.xml</file>
                </insignias>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
  <...>
</config>
```

> app\code\local\CompanyName\Insignias\controllers\IndexController.php

```
<?php

class CompanyName_Insignias_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

and

> app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/insignias.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
  <insignias_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="insignias/index" name="insignias_index" template="insignias/index.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </insignias_index_index>
</layout>
```

I have created the index.phtml file at app/design/frontend/base/default/template/insignias/index.phtml with a `<?php echo "worked" ?>` to test it, but when I try to access domain/index.php/insignias it shows me all the default magento blocks and a blank page in the middle where my echo should appear.

Can someone help me?

edit:
Here is a picture of my screen
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's anything in the log files?

--
Btw...
You need to call your block in the indexController.php before renderLayout()
The call would look something like

$myBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template', 'newpage', array('template' => 'newpage/content.phtml'));
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($myBlock);

--
You can find Magento log in /var/log within your root Magento installation
There will usually be two files by default, exception.log and system.log.

Answer (score 0):

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml

app/etc/modules/AMA_Checkout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <AMA_Checkout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout />
            </depends>
        </AMA_Checkout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/AMA/Checkout/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <AMA_Checkout>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </AMA_Checkout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <amacheckout>
                <class>AMA_Checkout_Block</class>
            </amacheckout>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/AMA/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Shipping/Method/Available.php

```
<?php

class AMA_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('amacheckout/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml');
    }
}
```

template:

app/design/frontend/default/base/template/amacheckout/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml